# downcasting using static_cast - pointers and objects

Tags: c++, pointers, object, casting, static-cast

say I have the following class types

```
class base
{

};

class der : public base
{
};
```

With static_Cast you can use objects and pointers.

I tried the following - which works (pointers)

```
base* b = new base();
der * m = static_cast<der*>(b);
```

However the following does not work

```
base b;
der m = static_cast<der>(b);
```

Any suggestions why the second does not work ?  Doesn't static cast deal with pointers and objects ? It works with pointers but it doesnt work with the object ?

Comment: There is no conversion between base and der (no constructor for der taking base, or conversion operator to der in base). There is a conversion between two related pointers.

Comment: How is there a conversion between two related pointers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first one, you are saying "I have a pointer, and I promise it's pointing at a `der`, so please just go with it".<sup>1</sup>

In the second one, you can make no such promise, because you unambiguously have a `base`, not a `der`.

---

<sub>1. Of course, because it doesn't *actually* point at a `der`, you'll get undefined behaviour at runtime.</sub>

Comment: You stated that `In the first one, you are saying "I have a pointer, and I promise it's pointing at a der, so please just go with it".1` Which part of the statement `der * m = static_cast<der*>(b);` states that  ? as `b` is of type `base` so how are you saying its of type `der` ?

Comment: @Oli Could you explain why it works with the pointer ? As i understand the expression `dynamic_cast<DestinationType> (candidate)` . The candidate is of type `base` and not der

Comment: @Rajeshwar Just focus on the right-hand side of the assignment. `static_cast<der*>(b)` says "Hey compiler, you're not sure whether or not `b` is a pointer to a `der` (maybe it's a pointer to another child class of `base`), but I assure you it is.".

Comment: @MistyD Consider if an instance of `base` takes 4 bytes (hypothetically). Then an instance of `der` has to take *at least* 4 bytes (to store the base class instance), and likely takes more memory (let's say it takes an additional 4 bytes, in this example). So when you try to do `static_cast<der>(candidate)` the compiler says "Hold on! You're trying to tell me that `candidate` is a `der`, but I can *unequivocally* prove you wrong: `candidate` is made up of 4 bytes, but all instances of `der` are defined to take up 8 bytes. QED."